# How to get output for a string in repeated manner in python?

Tags: python

```
l3 = ['Hi','Ki','Mi']
l3*3
```

o/p -> ['Hi', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Hi', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Hi', 'Ki', 'Mi']

How to get -> ['Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Ki', 'Ki', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Mi', 'Mi'][image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple nested comprehension:

```
l3 = ['Hi','Ki','Mi']

[x for x in l3 for _ in range(3)]
# ['Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Ki', 'Ki', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Mi', 'Mi']
```